# JSON named Array parsing

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm having trouble getting values from an array that I receive from an API request.

This is the code:

```
$list = $api->call("players.online.names");
$players = $list['success'];
echo $players[0];
var_dump($players);
foreach($players as $player) {
        echo $player;
}
```

The above returns NULL.
I'm expecting a list of the player names currently connected.

I find it odd that I cant use ['success'] to specify the array of values I want. This is the result I get from var_dumping the returned json:

```
var_dump($list);
```

returns

```
 array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["result"]=> string(7) "success" ["is_success"]=> bool(true) ["source"]=> string(20) "players.online.names" ["success"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(9) "test" [1]=> string(9) "Karqwe" [2]=> string(13) "name52" [3]=> string(9) "name2" [4]=> string(7) "name1" } } }
```

I'm somewhat new to PHP and I'm really confused as to why this wont work! I'm using http://mcjsonapi.com/ to connect to my Minecraft server and get this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are forgetting the outermost array.

Try this instead:

```
$list = $api->call("players.online.names");
$players = $list[0]['success'];
echo $players[0];
var_dump($players);
foreach($players as $player) {
    echo $player;
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Don't know how I didn't notice it in the first place.